# How to write Accelerometor data of apple watch to iphone's Documentary?

Tags: iphone, share, accelerometer, sensors, apple-watch

1. I read the Accel (sensors) data from Apple watch, and want to analyze it with Matlab. So, I try to download it to iphone's Documentary with the form of ".txt".
2. Now, I don't know how to write data from Apple watch to iPhone?
3. Apple provided "share groups" seems available, but it can only write key-values, I don't know whether it can write ".txt"?

Looking forward to your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared groups can be used for sharing just on WatchOS1, on WatchOS2 extension lives on watch not on iPhone. You can use WatchConnectivity for transferring data or files http://www.natashatherobot.com/watchconnectivity-say-hello-to-wcsession/

Comment: Thank you a lot, I have run a new "hello world" communicate project successfully, but when I try to add the code to the former code, the project only stop at "Finished running XX on XX's apple watch", which can't install on watch, and can't debug~~